# How to get "AdMob Network requests" using adsense reporting api?

Tags: admob, adsense-api

Been trying to build a little tools to monitor performance of ad units across different ad networks. But when I tried to extract data about my admob ad units using adsense reporting api, I found that I'm not able to get the "AdMob Network Requests"/"AdMob Network Request RPM" as seen in AdMob console.

I've tried the 4 RPM related fields:

- AD_REQUESTS_RPM
- MATCHED_AD_REQUESTS_RPM
- PAGE_VIEWS_RPM
- INDIVIDUAL_AD_IMPRESSIONS_RPM

But seems none of the above is what i'm looking for. Is anyone out there tried the same thing and worked? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Today the beta AdMob API was announced in the [Ads Developer Blog](https://ads-developers.googleblog.com/2020/04/join-beta-for-new-admob-api.html)

You also could checkout the [AdMob API](https://developers.google.com/admob/api/v1/getting-started) developer documentation [here](https://developers.google.com/admob/api/v1/getting-started).

```
curl -X POST https://admob.googleapis.com/v1/accounts/<your_publisher_id>/mediationReport:generate \
       -H "Authorization: Bearer <access_token>" \
       -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
       --data @- << EOF
{
  "report_spec": {
    "date_range": {
      "start_date": {"year": 2020, "month": 4, "day": 2},
      "end_date": {"year": 2020, "month": 4, "day": 2}
    },
    "dimensions": ["AD_UNIT", "AD_SOURCE"],
    "metrics": ["AD_REQUESTS", "IMPRESSIONS", "ESTIMATED_EARNINGS"]
  }
}
EOF
```

Check available [dimensions](https://developers.google.com/admob/api/v1/reference/rest/v1/accounts.mediationReport/generate#dimension) and [metrics](https://developers.google.com/admob/api/v1/reference/rest/v1/accounts.mediationReport/generate#metric) in the [mediation report documentation](https://developers.google.com/admob/api/v1/reference/rest/v1/accounts.mediationReport/generate).